# How to install kubelet, kubectl, kubeadm from source codes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm, kubelet

Because I have modified the source codes of k8s and want to debug the k8s, I would like to build and install kubelet, kubectl, kubeadm from source codes. Now I have built the `kubelet, kubectl, kubeadm` and get the bin files. When I want to run `kubedam` to deploy a cluster, I found just copying them to `/usr/local/bin/` does not work for me and I got the following errors:

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=x.x.x.x --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
W0204 20:55:28.785179    5682 configset.go:202] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.17.2
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING Service-Kubelet]: kubelet service does not exist
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR FileExisting-conntrack]: conntrack not found in system path
    [ERROR KubeletVersion]: the kubelet version is higher than the control plane version. This is not a supported version skew and may lead to a malfunctional cluster. Kubelet version: "1.18.0-alpha.2.355+845b23232125ca" Control plane version: "1.17.2"
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Could anyone help me about how to install `kubelet, kubectl, kubeadm` correctly from source codes?

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/

Answer (score 1):

If you have modified kubernetes source code and what to test those changes I suggest to follow the [developer guide](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/tree/master/contributors/devel) for that. It's hard to use kubeadm for testing modified kubernetes because kubeadm comes packaged with officially released  kubernetes and it's hard to make it use your modified kubernetes.

If you have modified kubeadm and want to test that you can follow the [doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/blob/master/kinder/README.md)

Comment: Now I have built the kubeadm as well and it is not from officially released kubernetes. How to use new built kubeadm to deploy the modified kubernetes?

Comment: First install a kubeadm using apt and then replace the binary with your kubeadm binary